# If topological space $X$ has the fixed point property, $X$ is a Kolgomorov ($T_0$) space

Tags: general-topology

I think this can be solved by considering the contrapositive of the statement and finding a continuous function without a fixed point, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x,y$ be points with the same closure. Define $f(z)=y$ if $z \neq y$ and $f(y)=x$. Since $x$ and $y$ cannot be distinguished by open subsets (an open $U$ contains $x$ iff it contains $y$), $f$ is continuous because the inverse image of any open subset is either $X$ or $\emptyset$. Any $z \neq y$ can’t be a fixed point of $f$. Therefore, $y$ must be a fixed point of $f$, so $y=f(y)=x$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $v,w\in X$ have the property that all open neighborhoods of $v$ are open neighborhoods of $w$, and v.v. (which is true if $X$ is not Kolgomorov).

Then, consider $f:X\to X$ defined as follows:$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x&x\neq w\\v&x=w\end{cases}$$

We know that regardless of topology, the singleton map $g:X\to X$, $g(x)=w$ is continuous. I claim that for all open $U\subset X$, $f^{-1}(U)=g^{-1}(U)$. This clearly would show that $f$ is continuous.

Case $1$: $v,w\notin U$: $f^{-1}(U)=g^{-1}(U)$ by construction.

Case $2$: $v\in U$, $w\notin U$ or $v\notin U$, $w\in U$: This is not possible by definition of $v,w$.

Case $3$: $v,w\in U$: $f^{-1}(\{v,w\})=g^{-1}(\{v,w\})$, which implies that $f^{-1}(U)=g^{-1}(U)$.

This map clearly is continuous and has no fixed points.
So,